# What is the default width size of Chrome DevTools when left or right docked?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is there any documentation or way to find out what's the default width of the Chrome DevTools window when it is left or right docked for a brand new user/account? I know the size typically persists once you change it, but I am trying to find out what the default size is when docked to the left or right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's **555px wide** when left/right-docked and **300px tall** when bottom-docked [[source](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:third_party/devtools-frontend/src/front_end/panels/emulation/AdvancedApp.js;l=59;drc=12fed693c9e273a68d1a84865d798f3bcdc7ad27)].